# Error on run app.js file (give me an error for the var line)

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, sockets, socket.io

I try to run my socket server (npm start / node app.js) and it gives me an error for the line:

```
var http = require('http');
```

In the char one (for the n of the var character).
if I delete this line the error continue to the next line with same error about the v letter of the var..
**image for example:**

[image: the error]

**When I run it in the cmd:**

[image: the cmd error]

help please I dont know what to do

Comment: Post error message console gives you.

Comment: @dfsq I uploaded image that view the error.. (image 2)

Comment: Could you please post code till 16 line inclusive?

Comment: @VladyslavNikolaiev: app.configure(function() - line 16
all code:
16 app.configure(function() {
17 app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
18 });

Comment: @Ben you posted all, but not the code I asked for)
I'm sure you have incorrectly initialized app variable, that probably is express server instance

Comment: @VladyslavNikolaiev Yes I'm using express and this is the line 16:
app.configure(function() {

Answer (score 0):

Try running `npm install` once to installed to required dependencies. Then you might be able to run the app by running `node app.js`.

Comment: Always post the error messages you see, else nobody will be able to help.

Comment: When I run npm install and after it I run node app.js: [image for example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jFSUK.png)
@alexf

Comment: please help I added an image at the last comment